# PHP Listing Dynamic Member Variables

Tags: php, oop, dynamic, object

How would I list all the public variables in an instantiated Object given that we do not know the variable names in the first place?

Scenario
A class may have a function declared like:

```
function addVar($name, $val) {
    $this->$name = $val;
}
```

I want a list of $names that were ever added to the object instance dynamically.

Answer (score 5):

[`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I would recommend you look into [PHP's Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.reflection.php) capabilities.